# Is there a package for easy drawing of ionization schemes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Is there an easy/fast way to create energy level schemes like [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termschema#/media/File:Energienivieau.svg) with Tikz? In the best case, I just want to give the energy levels and labels and the package takes care of drawing everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at the [`modiagram`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/modiagram/modiagram_en.pdf) package. Here a screenshot taken from the manual.

[image: screenshot taken from the modiagram manual showing the MO diagram of NO]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `modiagram` from Cle­mens Nieder­berger available on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/modiagram) could help.
Alternatively you could find some example on texample.net such as [hydrogen-splitting](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/hydrogen-splitting/), [the-perrin-jablonski-diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/the-perrin-jablonski-diagram/) or [principle-of-x-ray-photoelectron-spectroscopy-xps](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/principle-of-x-ray-photoelectron-spectroscopy-xps/)